# GWT resource bundle priority

Tags: gwt, resourcebundle

I have a GWT application which uses a style sheet which is defined in a resource bundle and the injected into my main entrypoint as follows:

```
MyResources.INSTANCE.main().ensureInjected();
```

I then also have another stylesheet that I make use of which which is served by my cms and is injected via the bla.gwt.xml file as follows:

```
<stylesheet src="cms/clientSpecific.css"/>
```

The idea is that styles in clientSpecific.css should override those in main.css but it seems that main.css (the one in the resource bundle) takes preferance to the one that was defined in the bla.gwt.cml (served by my cms). Is there a way to tell the GWT application which style sheet takes priority?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible as the `main` is injected in JavaScript which is executed at a point past the loading of the style sheets. However, even if you could get it to work, you might have another problem, because the injected main css is obfuscated (unless you disabled that). Thus the original stylenames are gone and the styles in the `clientSpecific.css` won't match.